# Can we get some sort of "You answered this question" indication on the list screens?

Tags: feature-request, question-lists

Sometimes when browsing questions I'll see an interesting one with no accepted answer but when I go to view it, find I've already added an answer.

Is it possible to have some kind of indication on the question listing that you've added an answer?

Comment: My gut feeling tells me this will be pretty expensive operation if this needs to be done for every user.

Comment: They don't even tell me I've already voted to close a question until I click the close link again and "d'oh" myself out...

Comment: Oh yes, that reminds me of a bug i forgot to report. If you VtoC then realise you should have used one of the other VtoC reasons and retract your original vote... then you can't do the new Vote... does that sound like a bug?

Comment: No, that is just so you don't abuse your close votes by constantly close voting the same question against the community consensus

Comment: @rene That would be a reason to not let you cast a second close vote *if you didn't retract your vote*.  If you've retracted your vote then you're not constantly going against the community consensus.

Comment: @NickCardoso It's not really a bug, it's just a feature that SE doesn't want to bother implementing; it's been proposed many times and declined.

Comment: Thanks, then I'll leave it well alone! It's not exactly a common issue in any case